# How can G3P oxidize into 1,3-BPG without energy expenditure?

Tags: biochemistry, energy

In glycolysis, one of the important steps is when Glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate is oxidized to 1,3- Bisphosphoglycerate, while reducing $NAD^+$ to NADH and $H^+$. I'm a bit perplexed by this step since it seems to yield a more energetic molecule, with several negatively charged oxygens which should really repel each other. This molecule is in fact so energetic that it's used in subsequent steps to create ATP from ADP (when it turns into 3-phosphoglycerate).

Despite this, no energy seems to be expended in creating 1,3-BGT from G3P. In fact, the $NAD^+$ can arguably have been said to *gain* energy from this reaction (according to my limited understanding), since $NADH+H$ is used as inputs during oxidative phosphorylation, creating *even more* ATP.

To summarize my question:

-Is 1,3-BGT a more energetic molecule than G3P?
-If no, then please explain to me why.
-If yes, then how can this molecule be created (seemingly) without expending energy?

I attempted to use "glycolysis" and "metabolism" as tags, to no avail. If there's a separate page for biochemistry then please let me know.